# Alterar o characterset do oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, codificação-de-caracteres, pl-sql, importação

Ao realizar uma importação de arquivo dump, o oracle esta me retornando as seguintes mensagens:
IMP-00019: linha rejeitada devido a erro 12899 ORACLE
IMP-00003: Erro Oracle: 12899 encontrado
ORA-12899: valor muito grande para a coluna `"USUARIO"."TABELA"."COLUNA"`(real: 41, máximo: 40)

A instrução usada para importar foi:
`imp system/senha file=arquivo.dmp log=imp.log fromuser=antigo touser=novo commit=y`

Pelo que entendi devo mudar o characterset da instancia do meu banco de dados, porém já tentei várias vezes usando o aplicativo `CSSCAN`mas nao consigo resolver de jeito nenhum.

Instancia de importação configurada como: `characterset "AL32UTF8"`
Instancia de exportação configurada como: `characterset "WE8MSWIN1252"`

Alguém já passou por isso, sabe me indicar como posso converter o characterset da instancia do bd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está caindo em um problema de `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`. O campo é, imagino, um `VARCHAR2` de comprimento definido por número de bytes (o padrão do Oracle) e não por número de caracteres. Para o Oracle, uma coluna `VARCHAR2(40)` é o mesmo que `VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)`.

Um caractere em `WE8MSWIN1252` é sempre definido por apenas um byte, mas em `AL32UTF8` há caracteres Unicode definidos por mais de um byte, no caso de texto acentuado, por exemplo. Assim, durante a conversão de *charset* feita pelo comando `imp`, os dados passam a ocupar um número maior de bytes e não cabem mais na sua coluna.

Para corrigir esse problema de uma vez por todas você precisa redefinir todos os campos para comprimento em caracteres: `VARCHAR2(40)` deverá ser alterado para `VARCHAR2(40 CHAR)`. O mesmo vale para todas as colunas do tipo CHAR:

```
ALTER TABLE [tabela] MODIFY COLUMN [nome da coluna] VARCHAR2([tamanho] CHAR);
ALTER TABLE [tabela] MODIFY COLUMN [nome da coluna] CHAR([tamanho] CHAR);
```

Você pode fazer isso em uma de duas circunstâncias:

1. Alterar todas as colunas no banco de origem. Assim, novos `exp` já não provocarão mais esse problema para `imp` subsequentes.
2. Gerar um arquivo .sql a partir de seu arquivo .dmp e alterar as colunas na própria definição das tabelas. Usar o .sql alterado para criar apenas as tabelas na instância de destino e depois efetuar o `imp` para popular as tabelas recém-criadas.

Para gerar um .sql a partir do .dmp, use o parâmetro `show=y` do comando `imp`, junto com `rows=n` para obter só a descrição dos dados, sem os registros:

```
imp system/senha file=arquivo.dmp log=imp.log fromuser=antigo touser=novo show=y rows=n
```

---

***Algumas referências***

- [ORA-12899: value too large for column (Oracle community)](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3730347)
- [Oracle alter table modify column Syntax example](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_alter_table_modify_column_syntax_example.htm)
- [NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS (Database Reference)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams127.htm#REFRN10124)
- [nls_length_semantics tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_length_semantics.htm)
- [How to get an Oracle sql text from a dmp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961295/how-to-get-an-oracle-sql-text-from-a-dmp-file)

Answer (score 1):

Um ótimo inicio para visualizar o problema destes erros específicos é utilizar o [oerr utility](http://www.rampant-books.com/book_0801_oracle_utilities_2nd_ed.htm) é um excelente dicionaro de erros do oracle e suas causas, neste livro ele fala sobre este erro que você esta lidando dizendo:

> Mas, este erro normalmente ocorre quando ha uma tentativa foi feita
>   para inserir ou atualizar uma coluna com um valor que é muito grande
>   para a largura da coluna de destino. O nome da coluna é fornecido,
>   juntamente com a largura real do valor e a largura máxima permitida da
>   coluna. Observe que as larguras são relatadas.

Para resolver você deve examinar a instrução SQL para verificar a correção. Verifique os tipos de dados da coluna de origem e de destino. Faça a coluna de destino mais ampla ou use um Substring na coluna de origem.